# get specific value of Data from cloud firestore

Tags: json, flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting my documents from cloud firestore with:

```
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("section").get();
final allData = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList();
```

However this provides me a list with Items like

```
{startTime: 9:54:34, stopTime: 10:34:34, date: 22.23.2323, duration: 324234, weekday: Mo}
```

This is not a json string, so how do I only get the startTime for example, or even better, how do I get a List with objects?

Comment: I'm curious why you are expecting JSON.  What you are getting is a List with each document represented as a `Map<string, dynamic>`.  Can you just reach into the map to get the property you want?

Comment: You mean like:
allData[0]["weekDay"] ?
That does not work like I thought. I am new to Maps as well but from that I learned till now it should work something like that.
I onced worked with json so this was familar and my first thought when I saw the output. Now I have to find a way around somehow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access to items inside your list like this:

```
print('${allData[0]['startTime']}'); // 9:54:34
```

I recommended to you use class model like this:

```
class itemModel {
 final String startTime;
 final String stopTime;
 final String date;
 itemModel({@required this.startTime,@required 
   this.stopTime,@required this.date});


 static itemModel fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
   return itemModel(
        startTime:json['startTime'] as String,
        stopTime:json['stopTime'] as String,
        date:json['date'] as String);
 }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
List<itemModel> allData = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => itemModel.fromJson(doc.data())).toList();

print("${allData[0].startTime}"); // 9:54:34
```

Comment: I updated my answer, check it out.

Comment: The solution at the top does not work for me because it requires a null safety and if I add one like print('${allData[0]![startTime]}'); it says The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.

Comment: The Json solution does not work either. It says "Instance members can't be accessed from a static method. (Documentation)  Try removing the reference to the instance member, or removing the keyword 'static' from the method." in the fromJson method

Comment: I updated my answer, forgot to add '' in reading data from map. Like this:print('${allData[0]['startTime']}');

Comment: I think some how you are doing it wrong.

Comment: I fixed it. You have to add an "as Map<String, dynamic>" when retreiving the data like:
'List<itemModel> allData = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => itemModel.fromJson(doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)).toList()'

Comment: ` List<fahrtItemModel> allData = await querySnapshot.docs
        .map((doc) =>
            fahrtItemModel.fromJson(doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>))
        .toList(); ` this works if there is only one doc. But if you have more it says it would expect a String but got Null